# AppEngine urlfetch broken on SDK 1.9.23 ?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The following code (see below) returns the following HTTP codes with different versions of the AppEngine SDK:

- 1.9.19: 200
- 1.9.20: 200
- 1.9.21: 200
- 1.9.22: [not tested, SDK not found in deprecated SDK directory]
- 1.9.23: **404**

All SDKs tested near- simultaneously, verified manually the page exists.

??

---

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.ext import testbed

tb=testbed.Testbed()
tb.activate()
tb.init_urlfetch_stub()        

http=urlfetch.fetch(method="GET", url="http://sports.coral.co.uk/football/outrights")

print http.status_code
```

Comment: Is this local devserver or on App Engine?  I'm not having any problems in production on 1.9.23 with urlfetch for GET, PUT or POST.

Comment: why would your unit test making request to external server?

Comment: Justin, this was indeed reported as the answer points out. We did rollback on this behavior in 1.9.24, and it did only happen on devserver.  In any case, if you have such a problem in the future, something that is an actual issue (since it worked in previous versions and stopped), I would suggest posting on our Issue Tracker: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to 1.9.24. I also had problems with 1.9.23 and narrowed it down to http request with urlfetch looked like proxy requests:

Invalid request using 1.9.23:

```
GET http://example.com:80/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Valid request using 1.9.24:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Some HTTP-servers accept both kinds of requests (the devapp server for example) but some don't (elasticsearch for example).

Comment: This is the bug (which is solved in 1.9.24): https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12123